# Horizontal Legend Leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, legend

I'm trying to make my legend horizontal in Leaflet but I'm not sure what I have to change. My base legend is based on this [tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html). Ultimately what I would like to have is something like [this](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/custom-legend/).

Is it just a matter of changing the css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to change the css, but also the javascript that is used to generate the html for the legend.

From the [section of the tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) where the legend is generated ("Creating a control with a legend..."), change the part with the comment "loop through our density intervals...", to something like the following

```
var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
legend.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
        grades = [0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
        labels = [];

    // loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each interval
    // first loop for colored legend boxes
    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML +=
            '<span style="background:' + getColor(grades[i] + 1) + '"></span> ';
    }

    // a line break
    div.innerHTML += '<br>';

    // second loop for text
    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML +=
            '<label>' + grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] : '+') + '</label>';
    }
    return div;
};

legend.addTo(map);
```

Then change the css to:

```
.legend span, .legend label {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 18px;
  float: left;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80%
}
```

Change the width, height and font-size as needed